# На смартфоне яндекс карта (метки и zoom) отображаются не правильно

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Сделал карту: [faili_na_razdacu/js/custom_map/custom_map.html](https://saitadmin.ru/faili_na_razdacu/js/custom_map/custom_map.html) как в [примерах Яндекс](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_map)

На ПК всё работает нормально, а на смартфоне метки отображаются не правильно, сама карта не чёткая, но если попытаться увеличить маштаб двумя пальцами, то всё становится на своё место и отображается как надо.
Подскажите пожалуйста в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: А в чём проблема? У меня карта отображается одинаково на ПК и смартфоне, но зум и там, и там не работает. Или вы уже всё починили сами?)

Comment: Что-то я там сделал, и вроде заработало, уже не помню точно)))